# directory structure between mac osx and linux

Tags: macos, unix

I found that there are some differents between Max osx and linux jsut like ubuntu, etc. is there any introduction about that, or is there any one can make a introduction.

for example:

1. ubuntu: /usr/lib/
2. 10.8.2 osx:

   1. /usr/lib
   2. /usr/libexec

Answer (score 5):

While you can shove libraries anywhere you want, and use OS X very similarly to Linux, I suspect you are after information on "the OS X way" of doing things, in which case:

Your question is too broad. While similar in some ways, there are many fundamental differences than between software packaging on OS X and something like Ubuntu - well beyond "stuff goes here on Linux, and here on OS X".

For example, libraries typically live in "bundles" rather than folders like in `/usr/lib` - either as `.Framework` bundles which live in `/Library/Frameworks` or `~/Library/Frameworks` (the framework bundles include headers, support versioning etc). Or shared libraries may live in application bundles... etc - each of these is a big topic by itself.

Without a more specific question, any answer shorter than a small book may not be very informative..

[This article](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/30/mac-os-x-directory-structure-explained/) explains some of the basic locations, and their Linux-equivalents

Apple's documentation on this kind of stuff is extensive (e.g [the intro to Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html))

Comment: Even better Apple doc is [FileSystem basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm gonna check those out too +1 to you both.